# Ternary operator inside Action<T> not working

Tags: c#, delegates, lambda, ternary-operator

Have an Action delegate and trying to use the ternary operator inside of it with lambdas:

```
Action<string> action = new Action<string>( str => (str == null) ? 
               Console.WriteLine("isnull") : Console.WriteLine("isnotnull")
```

Gives the old "only assignment, decrement, etc. allowed" error.

Is this possible somehow?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You would have to do it like this:

```
var action = new Action<string>(str => Console.WriteLine((str == null) ? "isnull" : "isnotnull"));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Action<string> action = new Action<string>( str => 
                    { 
                        if (str == null)
                           Console.WriteLine("isnull");
                        else
                           Console.WriteLine("isnotnull");
                    });
```

Comment: Are you sure? I think this would spit out something about "voids" not being equal or something like this...

Comment: and the question is specifically about ternary operator.

Comment: Aaaah, that's better, just got your edit! Yes, that'll work too.

Comment: @Bala yes, but he asked "Is this possible somehow?"

Answer (score 1):

I believe the ternary operator has to return something. In your case it's not returning anything, just executing a statement. As Reddog said, you have to put your ternary inside the Console.WriteLine call, which is actually less code :)

Answer (score 0):

The problem is not the lambda but the fact that the second and third expression in the ternary operator has to return something. `Console.WriteLine` has `void` return type and cannot be used as you are trying to. The solution is to put the ternary operator inside the call to `Console.WriteLine`:

```
Console.WriteLine(str == null ? "isnull" : "isnotnull")
```

You can use this expression in your lambda.